# Get Singleton Instance of Android Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio

I have an Android Activity. I want that this Activity is a Singleton. I did this by setting

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. Now I need a reference to this single Activity without starting it with an Intent.

I could create an instance like this:

```
MyActivity a = new MyActivity();
```

This would leads to a different instance than I would get when I do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

**How do I get the same instance of my Activity as the Android system creates?**

Comment: First of all "singleTop" is not a way to have an activity as Singleton. To make an activity as Singleton, you should use either "singleTask" or as "singleInstance" only this two provides Singleton instance of an activity.

Comment: Please visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490665/android-activity-singleton

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @Akbar The link does not help at all.

Comment: there's never more than one instance of a "singleTask" or "singleInstance" activity, so previous instance is expected to handle all new intents.

Comment: This still does not answer the question.

Comment: Short answer: What you are trying to do is impossible. But much more important: **Never ever ever** create an instance of an `Activity` directly. Kind of longer answer: Android does not work like you seem to believe. Everything that has to do with the UI is fair game for the garbage collector if the user can't see it anymore (locking the screen  or navigating to another `Activity` is more than enough). There is no such thing as a singleton `Activity`, flags like `singleTop` and `singleInstance` which by the way do two very different things just describe the behavior of the `Activity`.

Comment: And additionally if you ignore my warnings completely and start to hold a reference to an `Activity` somewhere you create two thing and twk thing only: a memory leak and an app which doesn't work. When building a mobile app think of it more like a mobile Web app. Pretty much the same philosophies apply.

Answer (score 0):

First you should be aware that you can not create an instance of activity by it's constructor and the only way is using intent to start it. The second point is the launch mode of activity that you should consider. `singleTop` means to bring the activity to top of the task not anymore and this doesn't mean that you have the same instance always, only if you have a created instance, android system use it instead of creating new activity in that stack. If you use `singleTask` the same instance will be used by system and the whole task containing the activity instance will be moved to top. And with a little different, the `singleInstance` launch mode means for system to use the same instance of activity in a single activity task and no other activity will be added to that task. And the default option is `standard` that after any intent to create the activity, it creates and launches a new instance of activity each time. I hope it was helpful.